# What feature of Django to make text looks shorter?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

if I have a title blog, and it is too long, it will make my website's theme broken when it is shown. How can I do to make it looks shorter?

example:
the full text: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
but when it's shown, it will look like this: "aaaa[...]"

Comment: Hint: Search for `text-overflow` and `ellipsis` :)

Comment: @Harry thanks for your quick reply. I will find it now

Comment: That is for general CSS mate. You may also want to look into the answer provided below as it is from the official Django site.

Comment: @Harry thanks you. I am beginner to web development with Django, so I really don't know what tag this question should be. I just think that I can do it with CSS or HTML, but maybe Django can do it too. Thanks you again

Answer (score 2):

You can use [truncatechars](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars) filter

```
{{ post.title|truncatechars:10 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with CSS:

```
p{
   width: 70px; //example width
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmkL0a7z/)